# Adding xml node inside node in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api

Please Review the code and suggest me how can i do that using C#

I have nodes below in string variable

```
 <state_tax_pin>d</state_tax_pin> 
<loan_amount>139397.0000</loan_amount>
<note_date>2009-07-27T00:00:00+05:30</note_date>
<orig_rec_date>2015-09-02T00:00:00+05:30</orig_rec_date>
<recording_information>sdf</recording_information>
<address>address</address>
```

I am trying to convert in to the below format

```
<state_tax_pin></state_tax_pin>
   <original_terms>
       <loan_amount>645000</loan_amount>
       <note_date>2002-04-05</note_date>
       <orig_rec_date>2002-04-16</orig_rec_date>
       <recording_information></recording_information>
   </original_terms>
<address>address</address>
```

plase suggest me how can i do this

Comment: yes but nothing  was useful

Comment: What did you try and which problems did you encounter?

Comment: doesn't appear that you tried anything can you show us what code you have actually tried.. please do not expect someone to code this for you without makin any valid attempts to do this on your own..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a root element.

```
XElement root = new XElement("root",
                    new XElement("state_tax_pin", state_tax_pin),
                    new XElement("original_terms",
                        new XElement("loan_amount", loan_amount),
                        new XElement("note_date", note_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                        new XElement("orig_rec_date", rig_rec_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                        new XElement("recording_information", recording_information)
                    ),
                    new XElement("address", address)
                );
Console.WriteLine(root.ToString());
```